# Unable to add a custom attribute to User model in Liferay

Tags: liferay, custom-attributes

I have a task at hand where I need to add an attribute (Home Page) to user model without making changes in liferay source code i.e. modifying the service.xml and regenerating the service.

I searched a lot on this but nothing seems to work. Used hook to override the create account page and all. Does anyone has step by step solution for this?

Only the steps will do as I just need guidance on this.

Thanks
Mohit

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to add custom attributes just by using the control panel.

[This link](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How%20to%20use%20Custom%20Attributes%20to%20enhance%20Users) should give you an idea.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that we need to use that programmatically and not using Liferay's UI as in using hooks or portlets

Comment: In this case these posts might help (http://www.liferay.com/de/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/adding-expandos-from-a-startup-hook , http://www.liferay.com/de/web/juan.fernandez/blog/-/blogs/4746086/maximized). Even though they are written for LR5, it should still be valid. Its basically the same mechanism as executed by GUI. Further search on Expando should also help in your case.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks a lot for the links. They guided me to the goal. I was not able to reply earlier as I am really short on time. Thanks for that help